# Error: "Maximum call stack size exceed" AJAX calling WebMethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik-grid

I'm trying to send a `GridDataItem` object that's retrieved from the selected row of a `RadGrid`.
But I'm getting an **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** error when I make this AJAX call:

**Edit:** When I run the code, my AJAX success fires, but the breakpoint I have on the WebMethod never hits.  After this, the pages freezes momentarily, then I get the error I mentioned above.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=btnTransferIn.ClientID%>').on('click', function () {
        var grid = $find("<%= gridStudents.ClientID %>"); //Returns an Object
        var gridSelItems = grid.get_selectedItems(); //Returns Array
        //var selectedItem = gridSelItems[0]; //Returns an Object

        AjaxTransfer(gridSelItems);
    });
});

function AjaxTransfer(selectedItem) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GradeSheet2.aspx/btnTransferIn_Click",
        data: { 'gsi': selectedItem },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: alert('Complete')
    })
}
```

**C#**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string btnTransferIn_Click(GridDataItem gsi)
{
    return "Done";
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

        <configSections>
        </configSections>

        <appSettings>
            <add key="AISAnalogPATH" value="\\tms-sse-01\tms_share\cbtExecutables\" />
            <add key="ExternalCAIPath" value="\\tms-sse-01\tms_share\cbtExecutables\" />
            <add key="AISDigitalPath" value="\\tms-sse-01\tms_share\cbtExecutables\" />
            <add key="AuthorwarePath" value="\\tms-sse-01\tms_share\cbtExecutables\" />
            <add key="QuestionMarkPath" value="\\tms-sse-01\tms_share\cbtExecutables\" />
            <add key="WelcomeMessage" value="Welcome to the TMS 2016 Program"/>
            <add key="Location" value="STL"/>
            <add key="TMSPagesConnectionString" value="server=tms-sse-01;User ID=xcv;Password=mumumu777;Initial Catalog=qwer12344567;"/>
            <add key="TMSConnectionString" value="server=tms-sse-01;User ID=xcv;Password=mumumu777;Initial Catalog=qwer12344567;"/>
            <add key="LogPath" value="e:\TMS\TMS_Log\"/>
            <add key="cbtPath" value="E:\C17CBT\"/>
            <add key="xmlPath" value="E:\TMS_XML\"/>
            <add key="TMSVersionId" value="2.0"/>

            <add key="PageHeight" value="750px"/>
            <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled"/>
            <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled"/>
         </appSettings>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>    
        <remove name="ChartImage_axd"/>
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
        <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx"/>
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
        <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
        <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
        <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
        <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>
        <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
        <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualC, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
                <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
                <add tagPrefix="TMSWeb" tagName="PersonList" src="~/TMS/Controls/PersonList.ascx"/>
                <add tagPrefix="TMSWeb" tagName="DateTemplate" src="~/TMS/Controls/DateTemplate.ascx"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>

    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.4" newVersion="2.1.0.4"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

</configuration>
```

I noticed, if I change the WebMethod's parameter to a string and I pass in a string instead of an object, it works.  So it seems like there's something wrong with the object or the way I'm passing it to the WebMethod.

I checked the object in the console before I make the AJAX call and I think it looks alright.. Although, I don't have a high understanding of all of it.

[image]

I hope I haven't left out anything too important.  Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post some code..

Comment: are you separating your JS in a file or is it a script tag? Posting some code will help understand more...

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but it's in a script tag.

Comment: Post your web.config file

Comment: Piero Alberto, No problem.  Will update question shortly.

Comment: post code of $find() and get_selectedItems() please

Comment: @ShiranDror I don't think those functions are open source.. If so, I don't know how to show them to you.

Comment: What happens when you uncomment "var selectedItem = gridSelItems[0];" and call "AjaxTransfer(selectedItem );"?

Comment: Exactly the same thing, surprisingly.  I'm updating the question now with some information on the types.

Comment: the error is in grid.get_selecteditems() according to your screenshot.  So it's not with the AJAX call at all

Comment: I don't see that in my screenshot.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot you posted, you are passing to `$.ajax` a complex structure. `$.ajax` will try to serialize this structure to JSON, and this is where things will start failing. **The error you get is one that `$.ajax` will generate if you try to pass a structure that has circular references in it.** For instance, this will cause an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error:

```
var a = {};
a.foo = a;
$.ajax("/", { data: a, dataType: "json"});
```

I'm not familiar with Telerik but the documentation for [`get_selectedItems`](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/client-side-programming/radgrid-object/properties/get_selecteditems()) mentions that it returns `GridDataItem` objects. [These objects](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/client-side-programming/griddataitem-object/griddataitem-class-members) have a `get_owner()` method which returns the `GridTableView` that holds the `GridDataItem` objects, and the `GridTableView` in turn has methods to get the `GridDataItem` objects that it contains. That's a circular reference right there.

You should go over the array of selected items, extract the identifiers that are meaningful to your application and pass *this* to your ajax call.

Also, you wrote:

> When I run the code, my AJAX success fires

Not quite. You've set your `success` callback like this:`success: alert('Complete')`. However, this is incorrect. You should set it like this: `success: function () { alert('Complete') }`. You must pass a function as your `success` callback. The way you have it, the `alert` is called *before* `$.ajax` starts performing the Ajax query, and what is passed as a success handler is the return value of `alert('Complete')`, which is `undefined`.